# React Navigation Error - TypeScript - This Expression Is Not Callable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm trying to find the best practice for this typescript issue I'm experiencing when I upgraded to React Navigation 5. The error I'm getting is

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '{ <RouteName extends "Stack1Screen1" | "Home">(...args: 
undefined extends SampleParamList1[RouteName] ? [RouteName] | [RouteName, 
SampleParamList1[RouteName]] : [...]): void; <RouteName extends "Stack1Screen1" | 
"Home">(route: { ...; } | { ...; }): void; } | { ...; }' has signatures, but none of those 
signatures are compatible with each other.ts(2349)
```

Here is the code I'm essentially using:

```js
import { StackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/stack';

export type SampleParamList1 = {
  Stack1Screen1: undefined;
  Home: undefined;
};
export type SampleParamList2 = {
  Stack2Screen2: undefined;
  Home: undefined;
};

type Props =
  | StackScreenProps<SampleParamList1, 'Stack1Screen1'>
  | StackScreenProps<SampleParamList2, 'Stack2Screen2'>;

const ThisScreen: React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const navToHome = () => navigation.navigate('Home');
};
```

Hovering over the `navigation.navigate('Home')` function displays the error message.
Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks! :)

Comment: What is the sense of using two separate types to describe screen props in navigation stack? Why you can't simply merge into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used something like this.

```
export type RandomParamList = {
    ScreenRandom1: undefined;
    ScreenRandom2: undefined | { screen: string }; // arguments
    ScreenRandom3: undefined | { screen?: string, params: { param1: string } };
} ;
export type HomeParamList = {
    HomeScreen1: undefined;
    HomeScreen2: undefined | { screen: string };
    HomeScreen3: undefined | { screen?: string, params: { param1: string } };
    HomeScreen4: undefined;
    HomeScreen5: undefined | { screen: string };
} & RandomParamList;

export type HomeNavProps<T extends keyof HomeParamList> = {
    navigation: StackNavigationProp<HomeParamList, T>;
    route: RouteProp<HomeParamList, T>;
};

const ThisScreen: React.FC<HomeNavProps> = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const navToHome = () => navigation.navigate('HomeScreen1');
const navToHome = () => navigation.navigate('Home'); // you will get error that Home is not allowed
};
```